# Struct definition in submodule provided and required in main module correctly, but getter does not work in main module interactions area

Tags: racket

In submodule "accounts.rkt", I have:

```
#lang racket

(provide account)

(struct account (owner type amount) #:transparent)
```

In main module "mainprogram.rkt", I have:

```
#lang racket

(require "accounts.rkt")

(define f (account "Jim" "Ledger" 123.45))
```

I hit f5 and in the interactions area:

```
> f
(account "Jim" "Ledger" 123.45)
> (account-owner f)
account-owner undefined;
cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

Why do the struct getters not work? Racket 5.3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `provide` use [`struct-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=struct-out#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-out%29%29), which provides all of the functions defined by `struct`.

```
#lang racket

(provide (struct-out account))

(struct account (owner type amount) #:transparent)
```

This provides `account?`, `account-owner`, `account-type`, and `account-amount` (as well as `account`).

Comment: I am looking at the Racket Guide, and it is not mentioned in the Programmer-Defined Datatypes but in the Modules/Exports:provide sections. Thank you Greg.